# Jquery datepicker not installing second time when month is changed

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on('change','select#month',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var month = $(this).val(); 
    if(month == "01" || month == "03" || month == "05" || month == "07"  || month == "08"  || month == "10" || month == "12"  ) { var eday = 31; }
    if(month == "04" || month == "06" || month == "09" || month == "11") { var eday = 30; }
    if(month == "02") { var eday = 28; }


    var today = new Date();
    var startDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), month-1, 1);
    var endDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), month-1, eday);

    $('#date-picker').datepicker(
        {
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate: endDate

        });
});
```

First time its working file but when i change month second time it is not working. second time its showing the last month detail which i have selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('change','select#month',function(e){
var eday;
e.preventDefault();
var month = $(this).val(); 
if(month == "01" || month == "03" || month == "05" || month == "07"  || month == "08"  || month == "10" || month == "12"  ) { eday = 31; }
if(month == "04" || month == "06" || month == "09" || month == "11") { eday = 30; }
if(month == "02") { eday = 28; }


var today = new Date();
var startDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), month-1, 1);
var endDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), month-1, eday);


$("#date-picker").datepicker("destroy");

$('#date-picker').datepicker(
    {
        autoclose: true,
        minDate: startDate,
        maxDate: endDate

    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: $("#date-picker").datepicker("remove"); will also work here.